# jquery attr('href') not working

Tags: jquery, attr

Update, problem solved. The issue was with a function that I was calling after trying to change the HREF, which was essentially changing it back.

---

Using jQuery, I am trying to change the HREF attribute of a series of links based on the hash contained in the URL, but the attribute simply is not changing, it's being changed to an empty string.

Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong here? Why isn't it working?

http://fwy.pagodabox.com/categories/sculptures/#grid

The links in question are

> All
>       Exhibitions
>       Installations
>       Objects
>       Prints
>       Sculptures

In the secondary nav

```
function navHash($navlinks, hashtxt) {

        // loop through specified links
        $navlinks.each(function(){
            var $me = $j(this),
                myhref,
                index;

            // Does this link have an href… if not move on          
            if( typeof $me.attr('href') === "undefined" )
                return false;

            myhref = $me.attr('href');
        index = myhref.indexOf('#');

        // if my href doesn't have the specified hash text, add it, else remove it
        if(myhref.indexOf(hashtxt) === -1) {
            $me.attr("href", hashtxt);
        } else {
            $me.attr("href", myhref.substring(0, index));
        }   
    });
}




   $j(document).ready(function($){

        var $navlinks = $j('.sub-nav li:not(.views) a');

        if(window.location.hash == '#grid') {
            navHash($navlinks, '#grid');
            $('.views .ic-grid').click();
        }
// so on...
```

Thank you!!!

Comment: Can you explain a bit better please, or create a jsfiddle with the simplest use case where you see this issue? It works fine for me. http://jsfiddle.net/CxeTs/

Comment: Can you create a http://jsfiddle.net that exhibits your problem?

Comment: Side tip: you can avoid the overhead of `.attr` by using `this.href` directly inside the `.each` callback.

Answer (score 1):

If you return `false` here you will stop looping.

```
if(typeof $me.attr('href') === "undefined")
   return false;
```

Return `true` to continue looping.

Comment: I don't think that's true... if I put an alert() there after the return false, it fires the correct # of times